# Objects passed as message in akka actors

Tags: performance, akka, message

I want to enquire what kind of messages can be passed between actors (routers, workers, etc). Is there a size limitation?

I am asking this question because I am facing issues where the transactions processed per second vary depending upon the size of the message. For example, I was using a string of size 5KB and passing it. However, the number of invocations per second was high, like 20000 or 45000.

When I pass a very simple string like `dust` then the processing is improved. In my *akka* cluster I have only two nodes and one generates the traffic and sends it to the other node.

Please guide me if there are some things that we should be careful about while telling other actors.

Comment: If you are using remoting to send the messages between the nodes then this makes complete sense.  You need to serialize the message and then transmit over the network.  The serialization and network costs are going to go up for a larger payload.

Comment: Hi, I'm experiencing this hit even when I have one node and I'm transferring data from one actor to another. In that case what would be the correct way to do it? the size of my string is about 5.9kb but  it is moved in the system about 60-70 thousand times per second.